# Angular $resource not passing parameter to Express service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, express, angular-resource

I have an Angular application that needs to be able to get construct data from a MongoDB collection.   I am using the $resource service in the flConstruct to request data from the server.  The “query” call returns all data and appears to be working fine.  When I try to retrieve data for just one of the constructs using the ‘get’ no data is returned.

I have printed to the console to look at what is getting to the service and I do not see the parameter being available to the findOne function.  Below is the output to the console

```
Get - constructs.getConstructById
constructData.id undefined
req.params._id undefined
req.query._id undefined
No Error - Construct Data Retrieved
Get - constructs.getConstructs (Id) - No Error
Returned - construct null
Get - constructs.getConstructs (Id) - Sending Back question
Get - constructs.getConstructs (Id) - Sending Back neither error nor question
```

//Angular service named, flConstruct

```
angular.module('app').factory('flConstruct',function($resource){
var ConstructResource = $resource('/api/constructs/:id', {id: "@id"}, {
    get: { method: 'GET', url: '/api/constructs/byId/:id', params: {id: "@id"}},
    query: { method: 'GET' , url: '/api/constructs', isArray: true },
    create: { method: 'POST'},
    update: { method: 'PUT' },
    delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}
});

return ConstructResource;
});
```

//Express config file named, routes.js

```
var constructs = require('../controllers/constructs'),

module.exports = function(app){


app.get('/api/constructs', constructs.getConstructs);
app.get('/api/constructs/byId', constructs.getConstructById);

app.post('/api/constructs', constructs.createConstruct);
app.put('/api/constructs', constructs.updateConstruct);
app.delete('/api/constructs/:id', constructs.deleteConstruct);
});
}
```

// Express controller named, construct.js

```
var Construct = require('mongoose').model('Construct');

exports.getConstructs = function(req,res){
var constructData = req.body;
console.log("Get - constructs.getConstructs");
console.log("constructData.id " + constructData.id);
console.log("constructData " + constructData);
console.log("req.params.id " + req.params.id);
console.log("req.query.id " + req.query.id);
Construct.find({}).exec(function(err,collection){
    if (err){
        console.log("Error - No Construct Retrieved");
    }else
    {
        console.log("No Error - Construct Data Retrieved");
    }
    //console.log(collection);
    res.send(collection);
})
};

exports.getConstructById = function(req,res) {
console.log("Get - constructs.getConstructById")
var constructData = req.body;
console.log("constructData.id " + constructData.constructId);;
console.log("req.params._id " + req.params._id)
console.log("req.query._id " + req.query._id)
Construct.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).exec(function(err,construct){
if (err){
    console.log("Error - No Construct Retrieved");
    console.log("Get - constructs.getConstructs (Id) - Error");
    res.send(null);
}else
{
    console.log("No Error - Construct Data Retrieved");
    console.log("Get - constructs.getConstructs (Id) - No Error");
    //console.log("Returned - construct._id " + construct._id)
    //console.log("Returned - construct.id " + construct.id)
    console.log("Returned - construct " + construct)
    console.log("Get - constructs.getConstructs (Id) - Sending Back question");
    res.send(construct);
}
console.log("Get - constructs.getConstructs (Id) - Sending Back neither error nor     question");
})

};
```

Comment: where are you calling the findOne function and passing it a param?

Comment: oh wait i think i see it here `Construct.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).exec()`

Comment: Your `getConstructById` method is looking for `constructId` in the request body but your GET request specifies the ID as a path variable. Also, GET requests have no request body

Comment: I fixed the findOne call.  I think I have it correct now.   I am still not able to pass the parameter to the function.   Can you please provide a little more detail on that.   Below are the changes I made:  exports.getConstructById = function(constructId,res) {
    console.log("Get - constructs.getConstructById");
    Construct.findOne({_id: constructId }),(function(err,construct){

Comment: I have isolated the problem to the Angular code.  IF I hard code the id in get of the flConstruct.js function all works fine. The problem is that the parameter is not being passed into the get of flConstruct.js.  I am having trouble understanding why?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. It is all within the Angular code.  The call to the get that is made in the flCachedConstruct.js did not properly define the parameter to be passed. I needed to include the parameter name, "id" as well as the parameter value, constructID. The "id" in this function call matches what I called the parameter in flConstruct.js.

```
flConstruct.get({id: constructId }, function(data) {
```